# How to align the image source within the ImageButton?

Tags: android, alignment, imagebutton

I have an image button that I want to take to entire width of the device. The image src I am using is not as long as the button.  The default seems to be to align it to the cener of the button.  Instead I would like to align it to the left.  I have tried using layout gravity but with no response.

Here is the code..

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:id = "@+id/llRoot"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="left"  >

    <ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/ibSend"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:src="@drawable/send" >
     </ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, I think you want your image in ImageButton to be alligned to the Left? Then add this to your ImageButton attributes:

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

and here it goes, your image is aligned at left of the ImageButton.

Comment: Name of the property is confusing, but all the options in scaleType lets you decide whether is you want to strech the image or leave it as is, or align it.